# Designing a Poker UI with Matrices and JButtons in Java

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, matrix, jpanel

I have to design a user interface in Java where all the possible combinations of hands for texas hold'em are displayed on the screen, so:
[image: Something Like this]

I understand I basically need 169 squares (Jbuttons) or a 13x13 "table". So I have encountered two problems, I can design an interface where I have these 169 individual buttons but how do I assign them? I know i need two for loops (one inside the other) to generate the list but i Cannot grasp how.
A friend of mine suggested I use a matrix instead of creating the buttons using a for loop....

This is my basic idea but i would like to change the colour of the buttons when I press them AND send whatever is written in them to a JText...

Any ideas are appreciated and thanks for taking time to read this

```
package modelo;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RangoImpreso implements ActionListener{

    JButton []ArrayButton = new JButton[169];//Buttons
    JPanel jp1;
    JLabel jl1, jl2;

    private RangoImpreso ()
    {

        JFrame frMain = new JFrame("Rango Pre-Flop");
        frMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 20));

        jl1 = new JLabel();    //jlabel that outputs number pressed    
        jl1.setText("Aquí ira el numero que se pulse");

        mostrarBot();

        frMain.add(jl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frMain.add(jp1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frMain.setSize(600, 600);
        frMain.setLocation(700, 300);
        frMain.setVisible(true);
        frMain.setResizable(false);
        frMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }

    public void mostrarBot() //method where the Jpanel is
    {
        jp1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(13, 13, 0, 0));

        for(int i=ArrayButton.length-1; i>=0; i--) //create buttons, add properties
        {
            ArrayButton[i] = new JButton(""+(i+1));
            jp1.add(ArrayButton[i]);
            ArrayButton[i].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            ArrayButton[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        RangoImpreso trin = new RangoImpreso();       
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //Use jlabel to show button pressed
    {        
        jl1.setText(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two `for` loops you need to create the buttons

- o = index of outer loop
- i = index of inner loop

both are counting from 0 to 12 so it will create 13*13 buttons

```
for(int o = 0; o < 13; o++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        //Create you buttons
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        //Add Handlers to change color and send text to textfield here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended Up using Jlabels instead and separate classes to merge them all later on one frame, having some fun with boxlayouts etc!!!